# Mongodb aggregation- $cond with $ne

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId,
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var teamAttendanceSchema = new Schema({
    allMembers: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }],
    currentDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}, 
    team_id : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'team' },
    presentMembers: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' }],

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('attendance', teamAttendanceSchema);
```

This is the sample of schema i am using. I want to get the count of the days he was absent. For this i tried with the following query:-

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
var user_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user_id);

  TeamAttendance.aggregate(
    [
    {$match : { allMembers : {$in:[user_id]} },
    {$project: {
            presentMembers : 1,
            absent: {  
                $cond: [ { $ne : ["$presentMembers" , user_id]}, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    },
    {$group : {
      _id : "$team_id",
    absentCount : { $sum: "$absent" },
    }}
    ]).exec()
```

But it return all days count. Don't know how the $cond work.

Comment: Add Sample data and expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as $ne can't compare array with objectId:

```
 {$cond: {if: {$gt: [{$indexOfArray: ["$presentMembers", user_id]}, 0]}, then: 0, else: 1}}
```

It'll check if userId exists in presentMembers array or not if it exists then he's not absent making 0 else 1 meaning he's absent.